# Getting values from UIWebView in iOS

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, radio-button

I have four radio buttons in UIwebview,i created that radio buttons using html,and i want to get the value of the selected button.please help me

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString* javaScriptString = @"document.querySelector('input[name="rate"]:checked').value;"
// run javascript in webview:
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: javaScriptString];
```